# Search and replace in vim: How to use "select text" for long phrases?

Tags: vim

I use the usual

```
:%s/this_one/that_one/g
```

for search and replace in vim. However, this method seems really daunting when the phrases "this_one" and "that_one" are quite long especially when both phrases are already present in the file I am editing. I would like to know some method by which I can simply use text selection for these phrases to replace the one by the other. Does such method exist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most users of the non graphical vim work on linux. There you can use the inline editor *sed*, which you can invoque with a file of replacement commands. I vave no unix system here to create you an example

Answer (score 3):

The generic method is simply to yank the highlighted text and reuse it in the command-line. Supposing you already have something selected you should get away with this:

```
y
:%s/<C-r>"/replacement/g<CR>
```

One could write a simple mapping, though, and use a named register to make all of that even simpler and cleaner:

```
xnoremap <key> "zy:%s/<C-r>z//g<left><left>
```

But sometimes the yanked text contains special characters, slashes or newlines that will make our substitution fail. Since we already have a mapping that does the yanking and cmd-line insertion for us, let's make it clean up the search patten as well:

```
xnoremap <key> "zy:%s/<C-r>=substitute(escape(@z, '\/.*$^~[]'), "\n", '\\n', "g")<CR>//g<left><left>
```

Reference:

```
:help i_ctrl-r
:help registers
:help substitute()
:help escape()
```

Comment: Except for the first command, it is hard for me to understand anything else. However, there I need "replacement" also something that I can select.

Comment: Copy the two strings to two different registers and use `<c-r>` for both. Use `\V` to disable most regular expressions if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers don't satisfy you, and you seem to want to keep your current vim learning level, the answer to your question is: no.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you use gvim:

1. Select an instance of the text to replace and copy it using the menu
   (or [alt]-e-c)
2. Type `/` and paste the text with the menu (or [alt]-e-p) and hit [enter]
3. Now select and copy an instance of the replacement
4. Type `:%s//`, paste the replacement, type `/g` and hit [enter]

Comment: I am sorry but I still have few issues with this. I don't have gvim so I am not sure whether this carries over to vim. Next, I have never seen things like [alt]-e-c and [alt]-e-p. I usually use y to copy and p to paste. Can you please give me vim specific answer? Thank you